# How to keep the URL unchanged?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my app there are several pages like `success.jsp,failed.jsp` etc.In the `index.html` page there is a form which calls a servlet for validation and after successful validation it goes to success.jsp and also to some other pages for other functions. To run app We usually type in the url `http://ipaddress:8080/app` and after the username and password matches it goes to success.jsp and hence the url changes to `http://ipaddress:8080/app/success.jsp`

So this means that user knows which page is forwarded after login.To prohibit from users to directly going to success.jsp I am maintaining session meaning if session is not present then redirect to index.html.

My question is I want to keep the URL unchanged.Which ever page is called the URL should always display `http://ipaddress:8080/app` not `http://ipaddress:8080/app/success.jsp` or `http://ipaddress:8080/app/failed.jsp`

This is the form

```
<form class="form-signin" action="valid" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" name ="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number" autofocus>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
<input type="button" value="Register" href="#" id="create-user" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
      </form>
```

This is the servlet mapping from web.xml file

```
<display-name>
    jsplab03Web</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>
        auth</display-name>
        <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        validation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/valid</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Please tell me how to do this

Comment: Can you post your form, your servlet mappings and any code that's using a RequesfDispatcher?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have updated my post,please have a look

Comment: Post the `validation` servlet. Are you performing a redirect?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes I am using `response.sendRedirect();`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the differences between redirect and forward.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181

Comment: How about `requestdispatcher.forward (...)`